# how to turn Child_process.spawn's "Promise" syntax to "async/await" syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, child-process

So I have this code and I'm trying to understand the async/await syntax in full depth. The below is the **Promise** version of the code:

```
function callToolsPromise(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let pipshell = 'pipenv';
        let args = ['run', 'tools'];
        req.forEach(arg => {
            args.push(arg)
        });
        tool = spawn(pipshell, args);
        tool.on('exit', (code) => {
            if (code !== 0) {
                tool.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                    reject(data);
                });
            } else {
                tool.stdout.on ('data', (data) => {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(data)):
                });
            }
        });
    })
}
```

I have some python code I want to execute in tools/__main__.py so that's why I'm calling "pipenv".

Here's my attempt to do write it in **async/await** way (which actually works):

```
async function callToolsAsync(req) {
    let pipshell = 'pipenv';
    let args = ['run', 'tools'];
    req.forEach(arg => {
        args.push(arg)
    });
    let tool = spawn(pipshell, args);
    for await (const data of tool.stdout) {
        return data
    }
}
```

But all I did was copy and paste from someone's example where I have `for await...` loop.

Therefore I've been trying to rewrite this same code so that I can actually understand it but I've been failing for days now.

Are there any other ways to write this code with **async/await** way without using the `for await...` loop?

Also I have no idea how I can access data except for using the `.then` syntax:

```
callToolsAsync(['GET','mailuser'])
.then(console.log)
```

How else would I access "data" from `resolve(data)`?

Many thanks.

Comment: Waiting for data on `stdout`/`stderr` only after the `exit` event seems like a very bad idea

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are probably not *better* ways to write the code using `async/await` than using the `for async (chunk of stream)` syntax in Node. Node streams implement an asynchronous iterator specifically to allow doing so.

This [article on 2ality](https://2ality.com/2018/04/async-iter-nodejs.html) has more in-depth explanation and discussion. MDN articles on [Symbol.asyncIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) and [for-await...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) cover asynchronous iteration more generally.

Once using asychronous iteration has been decided it must be used in an `async` function, which will return a promise.

While  using a `then` clause on the returned promise is a completely normal way of getting the data, you could also `await` the result of `callToolsAsync(req)` - provided of course that the call is coded inside an `async` function so that `await` is in a valid context.

---

The following code *experiment* gets the `stdio` and `stderr` output, and the exit code from a child process. It doesn't use Python or parse data.

**main.js** (type `node main.js`to run)

```
// main.js
async function spawnChild() {
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const child = spawn('node', ["child.js"]);

    let data = "";
    for await (const chunk of child.stdout) {
        console.log('stdout chunk: '+chunk);
        data += chunk;
    }
    let error = "";
    for await (const chunk of child.stderr) {
        console.error('stderr chunk: '+chunk);
        error += chunk;
    }
    const exitCode = await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        child.on('close', resolve);
    });

    if( exitCode) {
        throw new Error( `subprocess error exit ${exitCode}, ${error}`);
    }
    return data;
}

spawnChild().then(
    data=> {console.log("async result:\n" + data);},
    err=>  {console.error("async error:\n" + err);}
);
```

**child.js**

```
// child.js
console.log( "child.js started"); //  stdout
setTimeout( finish, 1000);
function finish() {
    console.log( "child.js: finish() call");  //  stdout 
    console.error("child exit using code 1"); //  stderr
    process.exit(1);
}
```

This showed

- A console warning that async iteration of a readable stream is still experimental in node,
- The `for await (chunk of stream)` loops seem to loop until the stream is closed - in this case meaning that `await` will wait on an open stream that doesn't have data available at the time.
- retrieving `stdout` and `stderr` content from their pipes, and getting the exit code can be done in no particular order since retrieval is asynchronous.
- Amalgamating chunks of data arriving through pipes from another process is **not optional** - console logs from the child process came through separately.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a example of "monitor*ing the* process exit codes or data appearing on stderr"?

Comment: Thank you for the amazing explanation. This has clarified a lot of questions I had for example the behavior of running multiple ```for await``` loops. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: This "for await (const chunk of child.stdout)" won't block, then? Meaning I will get stdout and stderr simultaneously?

Comment: @ed22 An `await ... of` construct won't exit the loop until the stream being read is closed or a `break` statement is executed within the loop body, blocking monitoring two streams simulataneously. It doesn't block the child process writing to stdio output - data written is stored in the stream's pipe until  read. If `stderr` and `sdout` need to be monitored and action taken before the child process finishes, then alternating between reading streams with asyncrhonous iterators is likely to be more complex than other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Its important to understand that `async/await` and promises are *the same*, just different syntax.

So *every async function returns a promise*!

so assuming you have a function returining a promise:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("done"), 1000));
}
```

there are two ways to consume the value.

Promise style:

```
function test() {
  foo().then(value => console.log(value));
}
```

or async await:

```
async function test() {
  const value = await foo();
  console.log(value);
}
```

Now its important to understand that your original `callToolsPromise` function is *not* promise style. when working with promises you *never* call `new Promise`. Basically the entire idea of of `new Promise` is to convert asynchronous non-promise code (and so non-async/await as its the same) to Promises (and so async/await).

Now *asynchronous* does not mean `async/await` but a more general concept. The other common way to handle asynchronity are callbacks.

So `tool.on('exit', (code) => {` is *asynchronous*, but neither a Promise nor async/await.

So the wrapping `new Promise` is basically used to convert this to a Promise style function that can be used as Promise or with async/await.

---

a last word about this snippet:

```
for await (const data of tool.stdout) {
    return data
}
```

this is a bit problematic. While node streams are async generators, this will return after the first chunk and break as soon as the stream receives multiple chunks.
So you either should replace `return` by `yield` and return an async generator, or concatenate the buffers with the loop and `return` after the loop completes.

Comment: @Lux I'm thankful for the insightful explanation. But I don't like the attitude of "because I don't know it, it's invalid". Rather assuming what the code would return, I suggest testing it first...

Comment: Thanks, thats why my AFAIK was there. However you definitly need to merge the chunks. `return` inside the loop will only work when there is only 1 chunk.

Comment: You're right, My apologies. Thank you for the suggestion. Fixed my code :)

Comment: The more and more I come back to this, It's made me realize the important concepts  in this answer. Thank you @Lux. Have a great day.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by using `await-spawn`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-spawn

```
child_process.spawn() wrapped in a Promise for doing async/await.
```

Comment: Thanks. a very elegant and easy-to-use solution. fits perfectly from my use case.

Comment: Thank yooooooooouuuuuuu! A very underrated lib! IMHO the best way to handle errors in an interactive context (stdio: `inherit`)

Answer (score 4):

direct answer:

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const process = require("process");

function cmd(...command) {
  let p = spawn(command[0], command.slice(1));
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    p.stdout.on("data", (x) => {
      process.stdout.write(x.toString());
    });
    p.stderr.on("data", (x) => {
      process.stderr.write(x.toString());
    });
    p.on("exit", (code) => {
      resolve(code);
    });
  });
}

async function main() {
  await cmd("bash", "-c", "echo one; sleep 1; echo two; sleep 1");
  console.log("This must happen last.");
}

main();
// run main() again & again , it will run in-parallel with the first main()
```