# How to wait to respond in node.js until child_process finishes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, child-process

I want to make an axios request from vuejs to a node.js server. This request triggers a python script on the server, which creates a file that has to be sent back to the user as a file download.

**Edit:** The code is actually fine. It's been obviously some server issues. Following I'll paste the code snippets for the sake of completeness.

I have the following prime-vue component to upload files to a server..

```
<FileUpload name="upFile" url="http://localhost:3000/upload" :multiple="false" @upload="processFile"  :maxFileSize="10000000">
```

This is the function that gets called after the file has been uploaded. If the promise is fulfilled, the returned file is being downloaded. The code is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49131423/15254044).

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3000/single-file", {
        params: {
          filename: event.files[0].name
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
.then(function (response) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', response.config.params.filename.replace('zip', 'docx'));
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      })
```

In node the file upload is being processed by the /upload route and moves files..

```
app.post('/upload', type, upload.array(), cors(), jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    fs.copyFile(req.file.path, '/home/ubuntu/bot/input/' + req.file.originalname, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    res.send("OK");
});
```

The /single-file route handles the rest, e.g. calls a python script and returns a file..

```
app.get('/single-file', type, upload.array(), cors(), jsonParser, (req, res) => {

    var filename = req.query.filename;
    
    const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python3',["/home/ubuntu/bot/bot.py", filename]);

    pythonProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
      res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
      res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
      res.download('/home/ubuntu/bot/output/' + filename.replace('zip', 'docx'));
    });
});
```

<s>When the child_process reaches the state 'exit' I get the following error..</s>

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

The response is sent almost immediately (~2s) after the request has been sent, even though the script runs about 30 seconds.

Comment: You can try using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), have you checked this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570325/how-to-turn-child-process-spawns-promise-syntax-to-async-await-syntax)

Comment: Thanks @PaulDigz, I think there was someting wrong with my server setup. The code I posted is actually running fine. Also I was messing around with the file upload component in prime-vue, so I split the upload and processing part into two seperate requests.