# How do I make this subprocess call synchronous in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

why i m getting this error `localhost didn’t send any data.`

Even i am sending the processed csv string from python to nodejs. The csv string is then printed (which is not happening) on successful form submit. Please see into images attached i am getting the csv string in the console but not in the csv file.

My `app.js` file which sends input (`csvData, req.body.keywords, req.body.full_search`) to the python script for use in processing.

```
/* csv to json */
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  upload = require("express-fileupload"),
  csvtojson = require("csvtojson");

var http = require('http');
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

let csvData = "test";
app.use(upload());

var server = http.createServer(app);

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});

// var db = new sqlite3.Database('./database/employees.db');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./Final')));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(limiter);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() { 
    console.log('server running on port 3000'); 
})


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./index.html'));
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

// Will remove all falsy values: undefined, null, 0, false, NaN and "" (empty string)
function cleanArray(actual) {
  var newArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) {
    if (actual[i]) {
      newArray.push(actual[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

function get_array_string(inp){

  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
    str = str + " " + inp[i]
  }
  return str.trim()

}

// form submit request
app.post('/formsubmit', function(req, res){

    // console.log("Form submit request")
    csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');
    filteredArray = cleanArray(csvData.split(/\r?\n/))
    csvData = get_array_string(filteredArray)

    console.log("URL list received: "+csvData)
    console.log("Search keywords: "+req.body.keywords)
    console.log("Full search: "+req.body.full_search)

    // return csvtojson().fromString(csvData).then(json => 
    //     {return res.status(201).json({csv:csvData, json:json})})

    // Send request to python script
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var process = spawn('python', ["./WebExtraction.py", csvData, req.body.keywords, req.body.full_search])

    dataString = "";

    process.stdout.on('data', function(data){

      dataString = dataString + data.toString()

      console.log(dataString)

      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.txt');
      res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
      res.status(200).send(dataString);

    });

    process.stdout.on('end', function(){      

    });
    
    process.stdin.end();

});
```

Below is the part of the python script which sends the csv string `export_csv` to the node js application.

```
if(flag == 1):
    # Get the output string   
    # print("################### - OUTPUT - ############################")
    found_results_A = list(set(found_results))
    found_results = get_list(found_results)
    found_results = list(set(found_results))
    notfound_results = get_list(notfound_results)
    notfound_results = list(set(notfound_results))
    found_keywords_list_changed = []

    for ele in found_results_A:
        found_keywords_list_changed.append(href_key_dict[ele])

    # Get the not found results correctly using set operation
    setA = set(found_results)
    setB = set(notfound_results)
    notfound_results = list(set(setB-setA))
    error_urls = get_list(error_urls)
    error_urls = list(set(error_urls))
    ######################################################################################
    ## CREATING THE FINAL DATA FRAME FOR COLLECTING the extracted urls
    ######################################################################################
    colList = ['Found urls', 'Not found urls','Error urls']
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = colList, dtype = str)

    maxlen = get_max_of_list(found_results_A, found_keywords_list_changed, notfound_results, error_urls)

    found_results_A = append_space(found_results_A, maxlen)
    notfound_results = append_space(notfound_results, maxlen)
    error_urls = append_space(error_urls, maxlen)
    found_keywords_list_changed = append_space(found_keywords_list_changed, maxlen)

    if(len(found_results_A) == maxlen and len(notfound_results) == maxlen and len(error_urls) == maxlen and len(found_keywords_list_changed) == maxlen):    
        dframe['Found urls'] = found_results_A
        dframe['keywords'] = found_keywords_list_changed
        dframe['Not found urls'] = notfound_results
        dframe['Error urls'] = error_urls

    try:    
        dframe = dframe.sort_values(by=["Found urls"], ascending=False)
        data = dframe.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
        export_csv = dframe.to_csv(encoding = 'ASCII', index = None, header = True)
        # print(create_json(export_csv.strip()))
        print(export_csv.strip())
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except Exception as err:
        print('Exception occurred, Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(err).__name__, err)
        print(err)
```

**I want to make changes in this to solve the issue but not able to proceed please help me to build this functionality.**

```
process.stdout.on('data', function(data){

      dataString = dataString + data.toString()

      console.log(dataString)

      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.txt');
      res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
      res.status(200).send(dataString);

    });

    process.stdout.on('end', function(){      

    });
    
    process.stdin.end();
```

Below is the error i m getting

[image]

Also i m able to render the html page which has HTML FORM

[image]

Output of console

[image]

Comment: Please help i am not able to solve this issue

Comment: From a cursory glance, it looks like you: 1) get a request, 2) set up a callback function for a spawned process, 3) spawn a python subprocess, 4) end your request without making sure that the callback function has been called. The solution seems to be: don't use `process.stdout.on` (which seems to set up an asynchronous callback function) and replace it with a synchronous, blocking call with a timeout. Or you need additional code to wait for `process.stdout.on` to actually fire.

Comment: @orithena i guess you r right about the asynchronous thing

Comment: @orithena can you share the syntax of making this function sync, i was actually searching for references

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't know how it's being done in node.js. You may have better luck by editing your question to "How do I make this subprocess call synchronous?"

Answer (score 0):

Data sent to `stdout` in the child process should be concatenated in an `on ("data"` callback in the parent process and only sent back as an HTTP response when the an `on("end"` callback is called. Refactoring the child handling code might look like

```
process.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  dataString = dataString + data.toString()
});

process.stdout.on('end', function(){ 
  console.log(dataString)

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.txt');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  res.status(200).send(dataString);     

});

process.stdin.end();
```

If the problem remains unsolved, or other issues emerge, try relaying `stderr` output received from the child process to the node console of the parent process with something like (untested):

```
process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.error( "stderr: %s", data);
}
```

This should allow you to put debug code in the python script that writes to `stderr`.

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571306/5217142) (of mine) goes into more detail about obtaining the exit code and data written to `stdout` and `stderr` by a child process if needed and of help.

[P.S. `dataString` may not have been declared -  I couldn't see a declaration for it in the post.]

Comment: `previous answer` link has two urls

Comment: `dataString = "";` is declared in `app.post`

Comment: Corrected the link, thanks. `dataString` should be preceded by  `var` or `let` to qualify as being declared :-)